# Terratest assert string fails with GitHub Actions

Tags: go, terratest

**Versions**

- Terraform v0.13.5
- Go v1.15.2
- Terratest v0.30.23

**Issue**

I've created a test according to the [Terratest Docs](https://terratest.gruntwork.io/examples/).  The code for the test can be found below under the heading: **iam_role_standard_test.go**

When I run the test locally, everything works as expected.

However, I'm using GitHub Actions as my CI/CD tool.  When the workflow job executes it fails with the following error (The workflow file is below under the heading **workflow.yaml**):

> Error Trace:  iam_role_standard_test.go:63
> Error:          Not equal:
> expected: "TestIamRole_dRGsKn"
> actual  : "[command]/home/runner/work/_temp/e5c5b8d2-62c5-4e73-b99f-d2e79eaa9765/terraform-bin output -no-color name\nTestIamRole_dRGsKn\n::debug::Terraform exited with code 0.\n::debug::stdout: TestIamRole_dRGsKn%0A\n::debug::stderr: \n::debug::exitcode: 0\n::set-output name=stdout::TestIamRole_dRGsKn%0A\n::set-output name=stderr::\n::set-output name=exitcode::0"
> Diff:
> --- Expected
> +++ Actual
> @@ -1 +1,9 @@
> +[command]/home/runner/work/_temp/e5c5b8d2-62c5-4e73-b99f-d2e79eaa9765/terraform-bin output -no-color name
> TestIamRole_dRGsKn
> +::debug::Terraform exited with code 0.
> +::debug::stdout: TestIamRole_dRGsKn%0A
> +::debug::stderr:
> +::debug::exitcode: 0
> +::set-output name=stdout::TestIamRole_dRGsKn%0A
> +::set-output name=stderr::
> +::set-output name=exitcode::0
> Test:           TestIamRole

Which, from what I can make out, is failing because `"TestIamRole_dRGsKn"` is compared to `TestIamRole_dRGsKn` which is not the same.

**Question**

How do I format the output from terraform so that the strings will be asserted as equal?

**iam_role_standard_test.go**

```golang
package test

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"

    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/random"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
)

func TestIamRole(t *testing.T) {

    uniqueId := random.UniqueId()
    expectedRoleName := fmt.Sprintf("TestIamRole_%s", uniqueId)

    // Retryable errors in terraform testing.
    terraformOptions := terraform.WithDefaultRetryableErrors(t, &terraform.Options{
        TerraformDir: "../path/to/terraform",

        Lock: true,

        // Configure backend to assume IamManager role
        BackendConfig: map[string]interface{}{
            "bucket":         "terraform-state-bucket",
            "dynamodb_table": "terraform_state_lock",
            "encrypt":        true,
            "key":            "my/key/terraform.tfstate",
            "kms_key_id":     "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "region":         "us-east-1",
            "role_arn":       "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-role",
        },

        // Variables to pass to our Terraform code using -var options
        Vars: map[string]interface{}{
            "create":                "true",
            "account_id":            "123456789012",
            "is_instance_profile":   "false",
            "name":                  expectedRoleName,
            "description":           "A test IAM role",
            "path":                  "/",
            "force_detach_policies": "true",
            "max_session_duration":  "43200",
        },
    })

    defer terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptions)

    // Deploy configuration
    terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptions)

    // Capture outputs
    actualRoleName := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "name")

    // Assert output vaules
    assert.Equal(t, expectedRoleName, actualRoleName)
```

**workflow.yaml**

```yaml
name: terratest
on: [ push ]
jobs:
    terratest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: '^1.15.2'
      - uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          terraform_version: 0.13.5
      - run: go mod init github.com/my-org/my-repo
      - run: go test -v -count=1 -timeout 30m
        working-directory: tests
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

It's referenced [in the issues](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/issues/706) of the terratest GitHub repo

Posting the answer here in case anyone else wastes a moment of their life on this!

Changing my `workflow.yaml` file solved it:

```yaml
name: terratest
on: [ push ]
jobs:
    terratest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: '^1.15.2'
      - uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          terraform_version: 0.13.5
          terraform_wrapper: false
      - run: go mod init github.com/my-org/my-repo
      - run: go test -v -count=1 -timeout 30m
        working-directory: tests
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```